# adding a read more on my html page giving weird behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Apologies, I *really* wanted to figure this out on my own but I've hit a dead end after many hours of trail and error.

I'm creating a personal resume website using bootstrap 4. I wanted to add a read-more button to collapse text to make it look better.

I came across this bit of code which seems to do the job :

https://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA

**html:**

```
<div class="more"> my amazing JD</div>
```

**css:**

```
.morecontent span {
    display: none;
}
.morelink {
    display: block;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Configure/customize these variables.
var showChar = 100;  // How many characters are shown by default
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "Show more >";
var lesstext = "Show less";


$('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
    });
});
```

what I've done is the following

added the JS to the bottom of my JS file,

added the CSS to my style.css

added in the relevant tag to my relevant area.

when doing this the colour of my text changes and the font changes from the standard.

I'm really amiss as to what Ive done incorrect.

this is my first foray into websites and other than python for data analysis I'm a total noob.

[image]

Comment: Do you have more CSS? Just plugging this in works without and visual discrepancies.

Comment: I can only assume that this is something from the <span> tags adding css to that section. Have you tried using the developer tools in your browser to see what is giving that section of text different css?

Comment: @Lucy I will have a look is the dev tool the same as inspect element? , Jerry yes I have 3 different style sheets if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @Datanovice yep! If you right click and inspect you should see why that section has extra css, then you can overwrite it with your own css, using !important or better: using more specific css identifiers

Comment: @LucyTurtle you are correct! there is `.white-vertion span {
    color: #000;
}` is this is what is causing it ?

Comment: @Datanovice this convo is getting a little long, and comments aren't really supposed to be used for back and forth conversation. Try adding the css that I provided in my answer to your page. If that doesn't work, then we should talk more in the chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the hidden text is wrapped in `<span></span>` tags, while the non-hidden text is not, there is probably some css assigned to the `<span></span>` tags that is not assigned to `div.more`. This can more-than-likely be overridden with the following css, or something similar

```
div.more span {
    color: inherit;
}
```

---

Note: it was found using the browser's developer tools that the opacity and font-size were being changed by other css, which can be fixed with

```
div.more span {
    font-size: inherit;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: this didn't work, but with your tip I was able to find the pesky setting that was causing the bug, so I'm happy to green tick your answer. thanks for the pro-tip, I feel like I'll be able to debug more easier in future, thanks Lucy!

Comment: oh and it was a different opacity and font-size setting, how annoying! thanks again.

Comment: @Datanovice oh great! I will add that to the answer in case someone else runs into a similar issue. Happy to help

Comment: Thanks again for this Lucy, got my site up and running you were a great help!